# I want to drop the data of a column cell in the database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

My program is incrementing every time I enter the program. And after 24:00, the program has to reset the value of the column to zero. But it doesn't work. Can you help?

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(!getTodayAtMidnight()) {
            PreparedStatement countLogin = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE amountoflogins SET Amount = Amount + 1 WHERE id = 1;");
            countLogin.execute();
        }else{
            PreparedStatement dropValue = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE amountoflogins SET Amount = 0 WHERE id = 1");
            dropValue.execute();
        }
    }
 
    public static boolean getTodayAtMidnight() {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date now = new Date();
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
        return now.after(c.getTime());
    }
}
```

Edited code

```java
Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet getDate = statement.executeQuery("SELECT current_date() = date from amountoflogins");

while(getDate.next()){
    if(getDate.getInt(1)==1){
        PreparedStatement countLogin = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE amountoflogins SET Amount = Amount + 1 WHERE id = 1;");
        countLogin.execute();
    }
    else if(getDate.getInt(1)==0){
        PreparedStatement dropValue = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE amountoflogins SET Amount = 0 WHERE id = 1");
        dropValue.execute();
        
        PreparedStatement setCurrentDay = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE amountoflogins SET date = current_date() WHERE id = 1");
        setCurrentDay.execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you are setting `c` to be midnight the next day, `now` will never be after `c` and hence `getTodayAtMidnight()` will always return `false`.

Comment: What needs to be changed?

Comment: Add a column with the current date in the table and check if the current day is the same as today's date. If not, update the date and to today's date and reset the counter to zero.

Comment: I changed, can you check?